# D3 with Backbone / D3 with Angular / D3 with Ember?

Tags: backbone.js, angularjs, d3.js

I'm working on a medium sized application that is going to include a lot of D3 charts / interactions in it. I'm wondering if anyone has tried to use Backbone, Angular, or Ember with D3, and if so, which one seems like the best fit for a front end MV* framework. The application won't be doing a whole lot of CRUD operations, mainly interactive charts and widgets to manipulate them.

Any comments appreciated!

Comment: I'd be interested in experiences with knockout as well. http://www.smartjava.org/content/election-site-part-1-basics-knockoutjs-bootstrap-and-d3js

Answer (score 12):

We used d3 with Backbone pretty extensively on a project that consisted of multiple "scenes". Each scene contained a set of different charts, and a user has the ability navigate from one scene to another. These scenes and their content all needed to be highly configurable (e.g. label colors and formatting, or indicating which data params should be plotted on a given axis).

D3 (rightfully) doesn't provide a view management system, which is where Backbone took over. Backbone Views served as wrappers for d3 charts. Predictably, Backbone Models served as the carriers of the d3-plotted data. But more interestingly, we also found that they served well as a means of controlling the appearance and behavior of the d3 code contained within the Backbone Views; essentially they served as [view models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). Since d3 promotes passing functions as arguments into other functions, these Backbone Models-as-view-models ended up holding many functions in them.

The following is a simplistic example, but picture doing this with dozens of properties. Using coffeescript here, because it's shorter (and better).

First, there's the model, which we instantiate inside (for example) a router's event handler. We populate this model with functions that will be applied to d3 selectors.

```
barChartModel = new Backbone.Model
  barColor: (d, i) -> if d.profits < 0 then "red" else "green"
  barLengthVal: (d, i) -> return bar.profits #// profits will be the prop we graph
  onClick: (d, i) ->
    console.log "We are", if d.profits <= 0 then "losing" else "making", "money"
  data: someJsonWeLoaded
```

We pass this model into a new view:

```
barChartView = new BarChartView
  el: "#the_bar_chart"
  model: barChartModel
```

A view might be implemented like this:

```
class BarChartView extends Backbone.View
  render: ->
    bars = d3.select(@el)
      .selectAll('.bar')
      .data(@model.get 'data') # <---- THIS

    bars.enter()
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('fill', @model.get 'barColor') # <---- THIS
      .attr('height', (d, i) ->
        @barLengthScale @model.get('barLengthVal')(d, i) # <---- AND THIS
      )
      .on('click', @model.get 'onClick') # <---- INTERACTIVITY TOO

  initialize: ->
    @barLengthScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-100, 100]) # <---- THIS COULD ALSO COME FROM MODEL
      .range([0, @$el.height()])
    @render()
```

Comment: Yeah, I was playing around with something like this. The problem I'm having with backbone is that we are creating new charts and inserting them into the DOM often. This leads to a whole lot of memory management issues with Backbone, or else I'm ending up with zombie views.

Comment: This sounds mainly like a side-effect of Backbone – not of Backbone+d3. But, yeah, it's something to keep in mind. It's worth pointing out that, depending on project specifics, you don't necessarily have to create an SVG element per Backbone View. There can be just one SVG, and each Backbone View gets a `<g>` element that d3 works with.

Answer (score 10):

I have used D3 with Angular on a few dashboards, and it worked very well. I have never really used Backbone, and not with D3, so I cannot compare the two. I chose Angular to complement D3 because it appeared to me that lately the D3 community has been using D3 with Angular the most of the three options you mentioned, so there were great resources available. There has recently been an entire book dedicated to using D3 and Angular together. I had also used Angular a bit before, and was aware of directives. Directives (in Angular it is a way to extend html tags) are great for meshing with D3. Each chart can become a directive, and then makes it extremely easy to reuse charts, changing only the $scope data. These are some resources I found helpful when combining the two:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqHBLS_6gF8 
https://leanpub.com/d3angularjs 
http://plnkr.co/edit/WnoCtNPV9azj0oPwv9kM?p=preview 
http://vicapow.github.io/angular-d3-talk/slides/demos/a-donut-chart-editor/index.html#/

Comment: I use D3 on Angular as well. I can't say anything about the use in Backbone or Ember, but D3 works perfect in Angular. You can use Angulars directives to encapsule the d3 charts. When you work in a bigger frontend team, your Angular developers don't have to know anything about d3, because it is packaged in the directives. My blog gives you a first insight how to setup a D3 on Angular Project http://goo.gl/jFU0xp Moreover you will find some other useful articles about d3 directives or even d3-plugins in an Angular application.

Answer (score 7):

I recently gave a talk on this very topic, here are some links: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ca3pQWc2-Xs) · [Code](https://github.com/samselikoff/talks/tree/master/4-apr2014-using-d3-backbone-angular-ember) · [Slides](http://slides.com/samselikoff/big-data-intro-to-d3-jan-2014#/)

---

I've done some smaller projects using similar methods to meetamit, but have recently started exploring Ember + D3. I haven't done much yet, but I think Ember has a lot to offer that could simplify building these types of app. Some things that come to mind:

- **[Computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/)**: you'll often be displaying aggregates, so slicing your data using computed properties means you just have to call your chart's update function whenever the data changes, and you're good to go. No more worrying about sending off an event to every view that will change when one specific part of your data changes. Plus, these will probably be properties on your controllers, instead of being calculated within a specific chart or view, which will make reuse much easier.
- **Storing state**: I had a tough time figuring out the best way to store state in Backbone. I started out trying to coordinate everything via events, but in the end landed on having a separate State model which acted as the brains of the whole system.

  I didn't get around to using Backbone's router much, but Ember's router + focus on state has made this design challenge easier for me so far. If you build within the system, you can click around your filters and controls, and everything just works. It may be possible to do exactly the same thing in Backbone, but there's something to be said for seriously reducing your cognitive load. You can also explicitly use a [StateManager](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.StateManager.html#sts=Ember.StateManager%20Class%20packages/ember-states/lib/state_manager.js:219) object - there may be some really interesting solutions here, though I haven't explored them yet.

Again, my experience with this combo is shallow, but if my instinct is right there are going to be many gains from building visualizations within Ember's conventions.

If you haven't already come across this, [Square put up an article](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/04/building-analytics.html) briefly covering their experience building an interactive dashboard with Ember + D3.

Keep us up to date on your progress + any insights you come across, and good luck!

Answer (score 6):

My group has used both angular and backbone with d3, and we like both for different reasons.

### Backbone

Backbone is a bit less opinionated about the way you construct your application, which is nice if you need to customize the way data is getting handled for performance.  You generally integrate d3 with a backbone view.

One challenge of working with Backbone is [memory management for complex views](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/), but using [marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) [helps with that](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#memory-management).  Also Marionette's event aggregator (and specifically [using request-response](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#request-response)) is a good fit for centralized data sources for coordinated views if you want to use something like [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) or [lunr](http://lunrjs.com/).

### Angular

Angular is more structured, and it is allows you to build up cool features very quickly. It has a steep learning curve, but I've found now that I'm understanding angular (having using it to develop an application for the past ~4 weeks), I've found that I can accomplish many of the same things I can in backbone without resorting to anything too hackish.

Like the request-response object in backbone marionette, using angular services allows you to build up complex views quickly.  You'll need to avoid using angular's dirty checking on $scope data for complex data visualizations to keep your application from bogging down, so the code you write for working with your data in angular is going to end up looking a lot like the code you would write in backbone.

I had resisted angular's "magic" for a while, but I'm starting to get won over by the speed of development you can achieve because of all the built in directives, scope checking, and other goodies.  Angular still allows you to poke around in its internals to speed up your code when that's required.  This "digging" may take more time than in backbone (because the code base is more complex), but I've found that time lost in this phase is usually recouped by time saved avoiding common bugs like memory leaks in view code and writing boilerplate code like view rendering and data binding.

### In summary

- Backbone is a good choice if you need extensive control and customization
- Angular is excellent if you really like data binding
- Ember is probably fine too, if for no other reason than [Square uses (used?) it](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/04/building-analytics.html), and Mike Bostocks worked for Square.
- In any framework the "hard" data intensive parts of your app are probably going to look similar if you write them well (i.e. get the data transformations into services and [put a clean simple interface around your view code](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/))

Answer (score 4):

## D3 on Angular

I use D3 on Angular since one year and I love the combination of both. Angular uses directives to create new and reusable HTML elements. When you have this knowlegde, you can encapsule a D3 visualization in an Angular directive without having D3 in your controllers or somewhere else. After that you can reuse the directive everywhere in your application to visualize your data. When working in a team of multiple Angular developers, the rest of your team doesn't need to know anything about D3, because your D3 code exists only in the directive.

Directives in Angular give you a flexible way of dealing with data. You can choose whether your data persists in your directive (then you will have a static reusable visualizaiton) or you make a data binding to a controller in your Angular application (then you will have a dynamic reusable visualization). The latter can be achieved by setting a scope in your directive

`scope: { data: '=' /* bi-directional binding */ }`,

setting the data in your controller

`$scope.data = [23,44,22];`

and join both in your HTML element instance

`<div your-new-d3-element data="data"></div>`.

Thats it!

Furthermore you can use watcher in your directive to watch changing data in your controller. A nice example of reusable d3 directives in Angular gives this example: http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077

Moreover you can find an easy D3 on Angular setup in this article: http://goo.gl/hNS8k1 
On this site you find further introductions how to use d3-plugins like the fisheye plugin in your Angular application or how to implement more complex d3 visualizations in Angular.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked  with **Backbone+d3** and with **Angular+d3** a little bit.

Backbone suffer with memory leaks problem and if you use backbone you should be accurate with garbage collection. However as mentioned before marionet or chaplin can easily solve this problem. If you want to have light and fast application I recommend you to use react engine for views and backbone models for other needs.

As to Angular it has more strict structure. However, I believe that it will be almost the same logic as Backbone. Angular takes care about architecture and everything what is needed just write code by refs and it will be maintable. Unlike backbone, where structure is your option.

**I recommend you to compare routing, bindings, models to select right framework, but not views.**

I always choose backbone + smths, often React. Because it is flexible and easy to manage application views. F.e. when we found react we moved from backbone to react to fix our mremory leak problems. However applicarion had about 50 views with different data visualisation tools with many controls. And we moved views step by step in two month.
It is difficult to do same thing with same efforts in angular.

Answer (score 1):

## D3 on Angular.js

I think these types of questions don't really have a right answer IMO, it's like asking someone whether they should choose a Subaru or a Toyota, when all they need to do is get from a to b :) Anyway, using AngularJS and D3 at the moment, so far so good :) There is a nice [AngularJS directive for D3 and NVD3](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives), if you do choose to go with AngularJS.

Also, check out this excellent [post on combining D3 with AngularJS](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html).

Happy exploring!