# Combining d3.js and backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js, visualization

I am working on a project which combines all the d3.js visualizations with backbone.js into a single page application. Since I have many visualizations such as bar chart, pie chart, and so on, i was wondering what the best approach to this problem is.

For instance, lets say I have a two bar charts, and a pie chart. Should I put all set margins, scales, render all data for all the charts together in a view? Since there are two different types of graphs, what should be the model?

What should go to View, Model, Controller, Collection, and so on?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is very vague. You'll have to be more specific to get a good answer.

Comment: What should go in the View, Model, Controller, and Collection shouldn't be any different than any other single page application. It has nothing to do with d3, bar chart, pie chart, and so on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050921/d3-with-backbone-d3-with-angular/17058009#17058009

Comment: An interesting video talks specifically about marrying the 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqSc9YAZUi8

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've looked into combining D3 and Backbone a little and there are a few existing solutions out there:

[Overview presentation](http://jtuulos.github.io/bayd3-may2013/#/)

[Short tutorial on combining Backbone & D3](https://speakerdeck.com/sameersegal/combining-d3-dot-js-plus-backbone-dot-js-to-create-quick-realtime-graphs)

[Longer discussion on marrying Backbone and D3](http://shirley.quora.com/Marrying-Backbone-js-and-D3-js)

[A bunch of JS libraries for integrating with D3](http://mikemcdearmon.com/portfolio/techposts/charting-libraries-using-d3)

I also found a library on GitHub but it didn't seem to be supported...

In the end, none of these really satisfied me so I developed my own Backbone models, collections & views. I set up:

`ChartPoint` Model - X & Y coordinate and a point label

`ChartSeries` Collection - Collection of ChartPoints that define the full chart

`ChartBaseView` - A view that interprets the data above, handles events, draws axes and other general functions

`BarChartView`, `LineChartView`, `PieChartView`, etc. - Specific views for rendering the type of charts you want.  Most of your D3 code goes here.

Not saying this is the "right" way to do it... just my way.

Comment: This sounds like an excellent high-level abstraction — could you post a gist showing implementation of the model and pseudo-code exemplifying the interactions between these and the other components?