# Possibility of creating reusable D3.js/jQuery data-attribute components or modules

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, nvd3.js

We are trying to create a component/module/etc. that takes the value of a custom data attribute and creates a D3 based pie chart displaying a percentage based on that data-attribute.

**Examples of the div elements with custom data-attributes:**

```
////// HTML 

<div class="donut" data-donut="22"></div>

<div class="donut" data-donut="48"></div>

<div class="donut" data-donut="75></div>
```

**Here is the CSS for it:**

```
////// CSS 

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #012647;
}

text {
  font-family: "RamaGothicM-Heavy",Impact,Haettenschweiler,"Franklin Gothic Bold",Charcoal,"Helvetica Inserat","Bitstream Vera Sans Bold","Arial Black",sans-serif;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 16rem;
  fill: #1072b8;
}

.donut {
  width: 29rem;
  height: 29rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

path.color0 {
  fill: #1072b8;
}

path.color1 {
  fill: #35526b;
}
```

**The D3.js / jQuery example we're trying to convert to a reusable compunent is below. (To see full working example go to this link - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgyCz)**

```
////// D3.js

var duration   = 500,
    transition = 200;

drawDonutChart(
  '.donut',
  $('.donut').data('donut'),
  290,
  290,
  ".35em"
);

function drawDonutChart(element, percent, width, height, text_y) {
  width = typeof width !== 'undefined' ? width : 290;
  height = typeof height !== 'undefined' ? height : 290;
  text_y = typeof text_y !== 'undefined' ? text_y : "-.10em";

  var dataset = {
        lower: calcPercent(0),
        upper: calcPercent(percent)
      },
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
      pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null),
      format = d3.format(".0%");

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 20)
        .outerRadius(radius);

  var svg = d3.select(element).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(dataset.lower))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "color" + i })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial values

  var text = svg.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", text_y);

  if (typeof(percent) === "string") {
    text.text(percent);
  }
  else {
    var progress = 0;
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      path = path.data(pie(dataset.upper)); // update the data
      path.transition().duration(duration).attrTween("d", function (a) {
        // Store the displayed angles in _current.
        // Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
        // During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
        var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
        var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent)
        this._current = i(0);
        return function(t) {
          text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
          return arc(i(t));
        };
      }); // redraw the arcs
    }, 200);
  }
};

function calcPercent(percent) {
  return [percent, 100-percent];
};
```

Comment: Have you read Mike Bostock's [Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)? It has a lot of good advice.

Comment: @mdml - giving it a read now - thx

Answer (score 0):

I experimented on using `Backbone.js` with my charts(I used NVD3.js).

Here is a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215669/combining-d3-js-and-backbone-js) regarding this

> 1. [D3 + Backbone](http://jtuulos.github.io/bayd3-may2013/#/) by @jtuulos (I personally found this link very useful to understand the whole concept of extending a parent class and instantiating )
> 2. [Responsive Charts with D3 and Backbone](http://blog.apps.chicagotribune.com/2014/03/07/responsive-charts-with-d3-and-backbone/)
> 3. [d3.js & backbone.js](http://bl.ocks.org/milroc/5522467)

I was able to create a parent chart class for the common chart types I use and then simply create an instance of that chart so I could re-use it when ever I want. Makes life easier when trying to maintain the charts.

May not be the best way of doing it, but I find this way very usefull.